# JavaFX Buttons grow with one pixel after their neighbor is pressed

Tags: java, css, button, javafx

I'm making a GUI in JavaFX, and I've stripped the window of the decorations that Windows did and I have made my own controls for `close`, `minimize`, and `maximize`.

The controls work great, but it seems that when I press one of them, it's neighbors change vertical size, increasing it by one or two pixels, as you can see in this image.

[image]

Why is this happening? 
Im also attaching the code I have so far in the `start()` method.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Menu Example");

    MenuBar file = new MenuBar();
    file.setId("file");

    Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
    fileMenu.getItems().addAll(
            new MenuItem("New File..."),
            new MenuItem("Open file..."),
            new MenuItem("Save file"));
    fileMenu.setId("#fileMenu");

    Menu editMenu = new Menu("Edit");
    editMenu.getItems().addAll(
            new MenuItem("Undo"),
            new MenuItem("Redo"),
            new MenuItem("Cut"),
            new MenuItem("Copy"),
            new MenuItem("Paste")
    );

    Button closeButton = new Button("X");
    closeButton.setId("closeButton");
    closeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        window.close();
    });

    Button minimizeButton = new Button("_");
    minimizeButton.setId("minimizeButton");
    minimizeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        window.setIconified(true);
    });

    Button maximizeButton = new Button("?");
    maximizeButton.setId("maximizeButton");
    maximizeButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        if(!window.isMaximized())
            window.setMaximized(true);
        else
            window.setMaximized(false);
    });

    file.getMenus().addAll(
            fileMenu,
            editMenu
    );

    HBox.setHgrow(file, Priority.ALWAYS);
    HBox.setHgrow(closeButton, Priority.NEVER);
    HBox.setHgrow(minimizeButton, Priority.NEVER);
    HBox.setHgrow(maximizeButton, Priority.NEVER);
    VBox.setVgrow(closeButton, Priority.NEVER);

    hBox = new HBox();
    buttonBox = new HBox();
    buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(minimizeButton, maximizeButton, closeButton);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(file, buttonBox);

    layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setTop(hBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 400, 400);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("Viper.css");
    window.setScene(scene);
//        window.setMaximized(true);
    window.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    window.show();
}
```

This is my stylesheet:

```
.root{
    -fx-background-color: #2D2E32;
    -fx-font-size: 11px;
}

#file{
    -fx-background-color: #3E3F43;
}

#file .label{
    -fx-text-fill: #EAEAEA;
}

.context-menu{
    -fx-background-color: #3E3F43;

}

#closeButton, #minimizeButton, #maximizeButton{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #3E3F43;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}

#closeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #E46458;
}

#minimizeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #80B1E0;
}

#maximizeButton:hover{
    -fx-background-color: #80E089;
}
```

Comment: Posting your stylesheet would be really helpful.

Comment: Done, even though I do not think the stylesheet has any impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your CSS stylesheet, adding the following selectors will solve problem :

```
#closeButton:armed, #closeButton:focused,
#minimizeButton:armed, #minimizeButton:focused,
#maximizeButton:armed, #maximizeButton:focused { 
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

**Reason:**

The default styleheet [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) defines the background insets of a `Button` like `-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;`, but if the `Button` is in one of the pseudo-states of `focused` or `armed`, the insets are modified as `-fx-background-insets: -0.2, 1, 2, -1.4, 2.6;`.

So actually not the vertical size of the neighbours will be increased but the "vertical size" of the `armed` or `focused` `Button` will be decreased.

This is what the selectors above prevent.

**Note**: If you create a new CSS class like

```
.windowbutton:armed, .windowbutton:focused {
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

then in the code you assign this class to each `Button`:

```
closeButton.getStyleClass().add("windowbutton"); // Similar to other buttons
```

the CSS structure will be a little but more clean.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted was `-fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;`, but your answer is the solution to my problem.